# Function app host keys are getting reset after zip deployment

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-api-management

What I'm trying to achieve is:

I've to deploy an azure function using zip deploy and associate that with an APIM.

```
$apiUrl = "https://$FunctionAppName.scm.azurewebsites.net/api/zipdeploy"
            $base64AuthInfo = [Convert]::ToBase64String([Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(("{0}:{1}" -f $username, $password)))
            $userAgent = "powershell/1.0"
            Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $apiUrl -Headers @{Authorization=("Basic {0}" -f $base64AuthInfo)} -UserAgent $userAgent -Method POST -InFile $filePath -ContentType "multipart/form-data"
```

Function deployment is successful, then I'm trying to add an APIM and connect one of the function to it. Here is the problem begins. Script and ARM template are valid APIM will get created successfully. But the `x-functions-key` that is getting added to the backend is not present in the azure function host keys list. Because of that I'm getting **401 Unauthorized** response while testing the APIM end point.

```
{
            "type": "Microsoft.ApiManagement/service/backends",
            "apiVersion": "2020-12-01",
            "name": "[concat(variables('apiManagementServiceName'), variables('functionAppNameWithaSlashAtStart'))]",
            "dependsOn": [
                "[resourceId('Microsoft.ApiManagement/service', variables('apiManagementServiceName'))]"
            ],
            "properties": {
                "description": "rigado-function",
                "url": "[concat(concat('https://', parameters('functionAppName')),'.azurewebsites.net/api')]",
                "protocol": "http",
                "resourceId": "[concat('https://management.azure.com', resourceId('Microsoft.Web/sites', parameters('functionAppName')))]",
                "credentials": {
                    "header": {
                        "x-functions-key": [
                            "[listkeys(concat(variables('functionAppId'), '/host/default/'),'2016-08-01').functionKeys.default]"
                        ]
                    }
                },
                "skipCertificateChainValidation": "false",
                "skipCertificateNameValidation": "false"
            }
    }
```

Any idea on this? Is this because of the zip deploy?

**Note:** One thing that I noticed is, if I try to run the APIM deployment bit later after the function deployment, it is working properly.

Comment: Trying checking these points.
1. You are not deleting existing function app while deploying, it should be incremental deploy.
2. Add the function app in the dependsOn field in APIM ARM template.

Comment: @Tarun Even if function app is getting deleted, I'm trying to get the key after deployment. So I think that won't be a problem.